# Mathematica with Portable R

Tags: interoperability, windows, rlink

I have on my Company Laptop no administrator privileges (Windows 7, 64 Bit).

After installation of R-portable and registering to HKEY_CURRENT_USER, I still cannot call R from Mathematica:
[image]

The first failure was because no Internet connection was allowed in Mathematica. After giving this permission, follows the advice to use RLinkRessourcesInstall. But also that failed. How to proceed? Thanks in advance.